# Drawing Circle in C++ using FLTK and some oddness between the book (PPP) and the result of the system

Tags: c++, geometry, shapes, fltk

In the PPP (http://www.stroustrup.com/programming1.html) book, Stroustrup has said the following subject about the Circle:

"*The main peculiarity of circle's implementation is that the point stored is not the center, but the top left corner of the square bounding the circle.*"

And these are the definitions and implementations from the book:

```
 struct Circle : Shape {

    Circle(Point p, int rr) // center and radius
        :r(rr) { add(Point(p.x-r,p.y-r)); }

    void draw_lines() const {
                if(color.visibility())
                fl_arc(point(0).x, point(0).y,r+r,r+r,0,360);
             }

    Point center() const {
            return Point(point(0).x+r,point(0).y+r);
             }

    int radius() const { return r; }
        void set_radius(int rr) { r=rr;} 
private:
    int r;
};
```

So the point we give the program is the top-left corner (of the square bounding the circle) and is not the center of the circle.
Please look at this simple code:

```
    #include <Simple_window.h>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  Simple_window win(Point(100,100), 600, 400, "test2");
  Point t(200,200);
  Mark m(t,'x');
  Circle c(t,100);
  win.attach(c);
  win.attach(m);
  win.wait_for_button();
}
```

As you see, I first gave the window a point (here the *t*) and used that point to be used for the circle shape, but if you run that code (I haven't such reputation to upload its image!), you can see, that point I gave it (the *t*) is not the top-left corner, it's just the center of the circle, on the contrary of his saying! What is the problem please?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the code or the description.

> "The main peculiarity of circle's implementation is that the ***point stored*** is not the center, but the top left corner of the square bounding the circle."

Note the phrase "point stored" - this is talking about the value the class remembers and not the value used to create the class. You create the class using the centre and radius and the class processes these values in its constructor and stores the top left and radius, as can be seen here:-

```
Circle(Point p, int rr) // center and radius
    :r(rr)
{ 
   add (Point (p.x-r, p.y-r)); // point is converted from centre to top left
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I don't know how I didn't notice that simple thing!